# How to validate a destination

Tags: jquery, validation, google-maps

I have to take delivery details(this is for a service providing site)from a user through a site.the snippet is attached below..How i validate whether the input is a correct location? Here,i have used google maps to prompt customer the locations, but he/she can add their own too.This may be a trouble when they add a wrong entry.Is there any way to overcome this? any guide on correct path would be a help?

```js
var inputPick = document.getElementById('pickupID');

var optionsPick = {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'aus'
  }
};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputPick, optionsPick);


var inputDes = document.getElementById('destinationID');

var optionsDes = {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'aus'
  }
};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputDes, optionsDes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pwd"><a style="color:red !important; font-size:18px">* </a>Pick up address:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input id="PickUnitNo" name="PickUnitNo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Unit Number (Optional)">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pickupID" id="pickupID" placeholder="Enter Pickup Address" required>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<!--Destination address-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pwd"><a style="color:red !important; font-size:18px">* </a>Destination address:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input id="DestUnitNo" name="DestUnitNo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Unit Number (Optional)">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destinationID" id="destinationID" placeholder="Enter Destination Address" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delivery address validation is typically done by validating the Postcode / Zipcode (+ Number) during the checkout process against a third party API that keeps this information updated. The other option could be to find all the Zipcodes and store them in your own database and then use that information to do the validations.

In your situation you need to make sure that the manually entered delivery address is validated.

You can find an example implementation that uses the Google API similar to yours here: https://gist.github.com/gabesumner/1801479